# Assessment help, application that interrogates tweets

Tags: c++

I'm a bit of a novice in terms of coding. I have to print to the console any tweets from a file that mentions a specific word like "Uber". 
This image below is what I have done so far. It prints how many times uber is mentioned in a line. But I need it to print the actual tweets themselves.

```
    else if (choice == 4) { // 4th option on the menu to print tweets mentioning the word "Uber":

        string temp;
        ifstream infile; // Read in.
        infile.open("sampleTweets.csv"); // File name in folder.

        if (infile.good()) {
            while (!infile.eof()) {
                getline(infile,temp);
                if (temp.find("Uber") <= temp.length()) {

                    cout << "Found Uber in the line" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to code-review. Unfortunately, your question is accumultaing close-votes, because (here on code-review) we only provide commentary on working code with a well-defined purpose and context; we can't help with implementing code to solve a particular problem. You might want to take a look at the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to get a better idea of how you can get the most out of the site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### [std::string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

In your code you have `temp.find("Uber") <= temp.length()`. `std::string::find` will return `std::string::npos` if the substring is not found.
So change that piece of code to

```
if(temp.find("Uber") != std::string::npos)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

### Print line

To print the actual line, just put it into the `cout` statement.

```
cout << "Found Uber in the line \"" << temp << "\"" << endl;
```

Comment: To the ones who downvoted: can you also comment on what the problem with my solution is?

Comment: You answered an off-topic question.